# Large mysterious margin on push in menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a "push-in menu" mobile menu to a very basic site structure.
The menu is based on http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

For some odd reason, when I click on the "Push right" button the menu has a large margin to the right. I am not sure why this is happening or how to fix it. It works fine in IE11 but not in Chrome v52.

An example of the problem can be found here: http://seyoum.net/playground/1/

I have tried to use the DevTools to pinpoint any CSS or markup that may cause the problem without any luck.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

---

This is what it should look like and what it looks like in IE 11:
[image]

And this is the problem and what it looks like in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: `here is the zip file with all the files needed` - don't bother, only fools would download it

Comment: it would be nice if you abstract the problem for us in a simple fiddle, instead of all this.. probably you will solve if on your own while abstracting the code (removing irrelevant code from the question)

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I have basically no idea where the problem lies I have gone through everything many times.

Comment: Have you tried the browsers "developer tools inspector" to check on the box model for each element - you should be able to get all sorts of useful information, including what exact css is affecting each element

Comment: Yes, I have. I can see that the large blank margin on the right of the menu is a part of the `body` but that does not help much.

Comment: wow, StackOverflow is a little harsh these days!

Comment: Also observable in Microsoft Edge. I couldn't inspect it, becase your code somehow keeps crashing my dev tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I forgot a closing tag for the `#page`. I am so embarrassed. I shall check my markup thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 2):

You've set your main wrapper to move -300px in the CSS, but you only want your menu to move. Remove this...

```
.overlay-wrapper.has-push-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

@media all and (min-width:320px) {
  .overlay-wrapper.has-push-right {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-300px);
      transform: translateX(-300px);
  }
}
```

A jsFiddle (free tool) would be nice next time, I used your link [to make one here](https://jsfiddle.net/hjf43tg8/). It does make it very much easier to answer questions. People who click on the question can look, solve, and test the solution quickly to make sure they really made a valid correction.

Comment: This is my fault as I should have said in the question that I was going for the push-in menu, not the overlay-menu type. But otherwise you are correct :/

Comment: OH! hmmm, let's see.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the blank space is that you have the following CSS rules (prefixed variants omitted for brevity):

```
.overlay-wrapper.has-push-right
{
    transform: translateX(-300px);
}

.push-menu--push-right.is-active
{
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.push-menu--push-right
{
    transform: translateX(300px);
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    right: 0;
}
```

The last set of rules places the menu "to the right" of the container. The second rule resets the translate, and puts it back inside the container. The first one moves the whole thing to the left.

Remove the second one and you should be all set.